# how htaccess redirect file not found contain special word to other file

Tags: .htaccess

I have links as sample: with "med_ " in the file name

> http://www.xaluan.com/images/news/Image/2016/10/09/med_357fa10d94d29d.img.png

I need to redirect it too the small file "small_" if it not found in server, and then if small_ file not found.. it will redirec to noimage.gif exiting on server

but my following code not work.. please help

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} images/news/(.*?)med_(.*?)\.(.*?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /images/news/$1small_$2\.$3 [R]
```

## thanks very much

udate: thanks I got answer from Croises bellow .. but need some bit more.. in case of small_ image not found too, what i need for the htacess make redirect to /noimage.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule images/news/(.*?)med_(.*?\.(?:jpg|gif|png))$ /images/news/$1small_$2 [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.(?:jpg|gif|png)$ /images/no_images.gif [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Great thanks.. could you help a bit more.. Can i combine two scripts in case the small not found too.. redirect will send to noimage.gif 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} med_(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule images/news/(.*?)med_(.*?\..*?)$ /images/news/$1small_$2 [NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ http://www.xaluan.com/images/no_images.gif [R]

Comment: I just give it a test 
look like only second rule applied ..
sample by going to: http://www.xaluan.com/images/news/Image/2011/03/05/med_1299376048.img.jpg    it will redirect to noimage.gif but not small_ which are on server ..

Comment: great thanks..this help me knowing about htaccess alot.. 
thanks again